# For loop to filter by lat every 5 decimal places

Tags: r, filter, bin

I need to write a for loop to use the dplyr::filter() function to filter latitude every 5 points, and then average the trait for each 5 degree bin.

I would like to do this for in 5 degree lat bins continuously from -180 to 180 and then o

The data frame is organized with 2 columns: lat and trait

so for instance:

```
lat             trait
-0.830361   0.113935
-0.795028   0.113935
-0.729722   0.113935
-0.729722   0.113935
8.021833    0.113935
5.473333    0.113935
5.436333    0.113935
7.366667    0.113935
```

I would like each trait to be average over the bin and then output into a df.

```
data.df %>%
  dplyr::filter(lat >= -180 & lat <= -175, .preserve= T)
```

The end output will be a data frame with one column containing all the bins, and the second column containing the averages

Comment: Try `data.df %>%
  dplyr::filter(lat >= -180 & lat <= -175, .preserve= T) %>% group_by(trait) %>% summarise(Mean = mean(lat))`

Comment: Latitudes do not span -180 to 180. Do you mean longitudes?

Comment: Thank you! yes sorry i was hasty in my message, I meant lat, but I input -180-180 instead of -90-90

Answer (score 0):

```
data.df %>% 
  group_by(avg_lat = round(lat/5)*5) %>% 
  summarize(mean = mean(trait))
```

Given more varied sample data below, you'd see:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  avg_lat  mean
    <dbl> <dbl>
1       0 1.34 
2       5 0.114
3      10 3

data.df <- read.table(
  header = T, 
  stringsAsFactors = F,
  text = "lat             trait
-0.830361   5
-0.795028   0.113935
-0.729722   0.113935
-0.729722   0.113935
8.021833    3
5.473333    0.113935
5.436333    0.113935
7.366667    0.113935")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a base R solution with `cut()` and `aggregate()`

```
data.df$lat_group <- cut(data.df$lat, breaks = seq(-180, 180, 5))
aggregate(trait ~ lat_group, data = data.df, FUN = mean)

  lat_group     trait
1    (-5,0] 1.3354512
2    (5,10] 0.8354512

aggregate(data.df[, c('lat', 'trait')], by = data.df['lat_group'], FUN = mean)
#or
#aggregate(data.df[, c('lat', 'trait')], by = list(lat_group = data.df$lat_group), FUN = mean)

  lat_group        lat     trait
1    (-5,0] -0.7712082 1.3354512
2    (5,10]  6.5745415 0.8354512
```

**Data** (copying and pasting from @Jon Spring)

```
data.df <- read.table(
  header = T, 
  stringsAsFactors = F,
  text = "lat             trait
  -0.830361   5
  -0.795028   0.113935
  -0.729722   0.113935
  -0.729722   0.113935
  8.021833    3
  5.473333    0.113935
  5.436333    0.113935
  7.366667    0.113935")
```